# Why is the explicit cast necessary here

Tags: c#

I am using a factory similar to this:

```
interface I<T>
{
    void Print();
}

class A : I<A>
{
    public string Id { get; }
    public A(string id) { Id = id; }
    public void Print() { Console.WriteLine(Id); }
}

class B : I<B>
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public B(int id) { Id = id; }
    public void Print() { Console.WriteLine(Id); }
}

class Factory
{
    public T Create<T>()
        where T : I<T>
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
            return (T)(I<T>)new A("A");
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
            return (T)(I<T>)new B(2);
        else
            throw new Exception("Unknown className");
    }
}

var sut = new Factory();
sut.Create<A>().Print();
sut.Create<B>().Print();
```

What I do not fully understand is: why is this double cast

```
(T)(I<T>)new A()
```

necessary? The compiler knows that

```
new A("A") is I<A>
```

and actually knows that

```
new A("A") is T
```

BTW: I am using the generic interface, since otherwise

```
Create<I>()
```

would compile fine but is not desired here.

Comment: This is probably a direct duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/11555729/… In short there are a couple of smells here, and the compiler error is static analysis trying to save your from making a runtime mistake

Comment: The double cast means all bets are off, you have lost your type safety, Also using `typeof(T)` inside a generic method is usually (not always) but usually a time to rethink your problem

Comment: I agree with TheGeneral. You better split this method into `CreateA`, `CreateB` etc. Anyway, you will add new condition or new method for new type, but the approach with methods does not have that problem so it will be the right approach. And if you don't use `T` in `I<T>` interface, why do you need it at all?

Comment: @TheGeneral I agree that the generic Create method is funny somehow and that one should rather use dedicated factory methods per type, but the real code uses the Create method to map an input object to results of divers types and doing this in a generic method is the only way to reuse the mapping code I found so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code reasons that when `typeof(T) == typeof(A)` is `true`, it guarantees that the type of expression `new A(...)` is compatible with `T`.

Though this reasoning is correct at runtime, C# compiler doesn't treat `typeof(T) == typeof(A)` as any kind of "type guard".

> The compiler knows that `new A("A")` is`I<A>`

Agree

> and actually knows that `new A("A")` is `T`

Nope, it cannot. In template-based approach (e.g. in C++) the "generic" function is compiled per every `T` encountered in source code, and then the compiler knows. However in .NET the generics is runtime-based, so that C# compiler must compile a code that would work for any `T` complying with the constraints, but besides that the concrete `T` is not known at compile time.

If you want to employ compiler "type guards" and avoid explicit casts, you can rewrite your code using [C# pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression):

```cs
public T Create<T>()
    where T : I<T>
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(A) && new A("A") is T retA)
        return retA;
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(B) && new B(2) is T retB)
        return retB;
    else
        throw new Exception("Unknown className");
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best explanation so far (and there are some good ones already) plus a nice refactor (which I have to read up on to understand)

Answer (score 2):

> and actually knows that
>
> `new A("A") is T`

No. If it knows that `A` is `I<A>`, does not mean that `A` and `T` is the same. `T` may be `B` and your cast will fail. Look at this code:

```
public T Create<T>()
    where T : I<T>
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
        return (T)(I<T>)new B(2);
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
        return (T)(I<T>)new A("A");
    else
        throw new Exception("Unknown className");
}
```

I swapped `A` and `B` and you cast `B` to `A`. The cast is invalid.

Comment: This demonstrates the runtime/compile time issue of my question

Answer (score 2):

Compiler knows that there is type conversion between `A` ->`I<A>` and `B` -> `I<B>` it also knows that there is conversion between `T` and `I<T>`. But the necessarily link is missing - direct conversion between `A` and `T`. So it fails.

If I knew for certain that all concrete types like `A` and `B` that I want to create are classes I'd use `class` type constraint. It allows us to simplify our code, with some refactoring that permitted myself the code might be something along the lines of:

```
public T Create<T>() where T : class, I<T>
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
    {
        return new A("A") as T;
    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
    {
        return new B(2) as T;
    }
    throw new Exception("Unknown className");
}
```

Comment: This will give you a disturbing "CS8603: Possible null reference return."

Answer (score 2):

> What I do not fully understand is: why is this double cast
>   necessary? The compiler knows that

What compiler knows is following

```
A is I<A>
B is I<B>
T is I<T>
T is not A
T is not I<A>
T is not B
T is not I<B>
```

That's why an instance of T must be cast to parent interface first then down to specific type.